# Oracle function to get account balance

Tags: oracle, function

I have customers, which have multiple accounts. For each account I keep a separate balance.

As you can see below I can produce a detailed daily summary of each account. What would be the best way to wrap this detail into a function, which returns only the final balance of the account?

```
ALTER SESSION SET NLS_DATE_FORMAT = 'DD-MON-YYYY HH24:MI:SS';


CREATE TABLE CUSTOMERS (
CUSTOMER_ID, FIRST_NAME, LAST_NAME,IS_ACTIVE) AS 
SELECT 'A355135', 'Otto', 'Vatsch','Y' FROM DUAL  UNION ALL 
SELECT 'B375480', 'Sophia', 'Fazio','Y' FROM DUAL  UNION ALL 
SELECT 'C378853', 'Brian', 'Vendome','Y' FROM DUAL  UNION ALL 
SELECT 'D379171', 'John', 'Carucci','Y' FROM DUAL  UNION ALL 
SELECT 'E379466', 'Bonnie', 'Winterbottom','Y' FROM DUAL  UNION ALL 
SELECT 'F379739', 'Debra', 'Caygle','Y' FROM DUAL  UNION ALL 
SELECT 'G379994', 'Jerry', 'Torciano','Y' FROM DUAL  UNION ALL
SELECT 'H380235', 'Karl', 'Malden','Y' FROM DUAL  UNION ALL
SELECT 'I380492', 'Joseph', 'Zaza','Y' FROM DUAL  UNION ALL
SELECT 'J380753', 'Tom', 'Micelli','Y' FROM DUAL  UNION ALL
SELECT 'K380989', 'Lisa', 'Saladino','Y' FROM DUAL  UNION ALL
SELECT 'L381307', 'Jeff', 'Lebowitz','Y' FROM DUAL  UNION ALL
SELECT 'M381569', 'Brian', 'Zanona','Y' FROM DUAL  UNION ALL
SELECT 'N381823', 'Seth', 'Bobet','Y' FROM DUAL  UNION ALL
SELECT 'O382059', 'Mitch', 'Weinreb','Y' FROM DUAL  UNION ALL
SELECT 'P382319', 'Roz', 'Stern','Y' FROM DUAL  UNION ALL
SELECT 'Q382564', 'Zoey', 'Zanzone','Y' FROM DUAL  UNION ALL
SELECT 'R382815', 'Diane', 'Stein','Y' FROM DUAL  UNION ALL
SELECT 'S441015', 'Tony', 'Dimeo','Y' FROM DUAL  UNION ALL
SELECT 'T441333', 'Faith', 'Carrucci','Y' FROM DUAL  UNION ALL
SELECT 'X098533', 'Brian', 'Tessio','Y' FROM DUAL  UNION ALL
SELECT 'Y098273', 'Cheryl', 'Brasi','Y' FROM DUAL  UNION ALL
SELECT 'Z098555', 'Peter', 'Clemenza','Y' FROM DUAL;

CREATE TABLE CUSTOMER_ACCOUNTS (
ACCOUNT_NUMBER,
CUSTOMER_ID, VENDOR_ID,
IS_ACTIVE) AS 
SELECT 'B17ARWYYZRCU2Q2', 
'D379171', 8, 'Y' FROM DUAL  UNION ALL 
SELECT '0T81Z07CS6LXQ7Z',
'D379171', 7, 'Y' FROM DUAL  UNION ALL 
SELECT 'YWYXC3Q5N9XZ7S',
'D379171', 7, 'Y' FROM DUAL  UNION ALL 
SELECT '612ZKAQ66VA3W3',
'D379171', 4, 'Y' FROM DUAL  UNION ALL 
SELECT 'THVQD6M9LR7AVK', 'E379466', 5, 'Y' FROM DUAL  UNION ALL 
SELECT 'CFM9K06ZR98R9H2', 'K380989', 1, 'Y' FROM DUAL  UNION ALL 
SELECT '0Z8NQN6JZRZWFPX',
'K380989',  2, 'Y' FROM DUAL  UNION ALL 
SELECT 'BCHD9TW78W67S1D',
 'K380989', 3, 'Y' FROM DUAL  UNION ALL 
SELECT '01SUV1Y3BJTCFXY',
'X098533', 1, 'Y' FROM DUAL  UNION ALL 
SELECT 'TAJ3N5EB9ZX7AD',
'X098533', 2, 'Y' FROM DUAL  UNION ALL 
SELECT 'Y88JTBCP8SUFY8',
'X098533', 3, 'Y' FROM DUAL  UNION ALL 
SELECT '06LP3CYJLS01F2L',
'Y098273', 7, 'Y' FROM DUAL  UNION ALL 
SELECT 'TFWVBRC5QHQLC4', 'Y098273', 8, 'Y' FROM DUAL  UNION ALL 
SELECT '0Z76WT5NTLRZPTW', 'Z098555', 10, 'Y' FROM DUAL;

create table transactions (
     transaction_id NUMBER GENERATED BY DEFAULT AS IDENTITY,
    account_number VARCHAR2(15),
    transaction_type varchar2(1),
    transaction_amount NUMBER(10,2),
     transaction_date DATE
);

insert  into transactions(
account_number, transaction_type, transaction_amount, transaction_date)
SELECT '0Z8NQN6JZRZWFPX', 'D', 1000 * LEVEL, date '2023-03-29' + level * interval '2' day from dual
          connect by level <= 3
union all
SELECT '0Z8NQN6JZRZWFPX', 'C', 500 * LEVEL, date '2023-03-30' + level * interval '2' day from dual
          connect by level <= 2


WITH  daily_summary  AS
(
    SELECT  
account_number,
 transaction_date
    ,    SUM (DECODE (transaction_type, 'C', transaction_amount, 0))    AS credit_total
    ,    SUM (DECODE (transaction_type, 'D', transaction_amount , 0))   AS debit_total
    FROM     transactions
    GROUP BY  account_number, transaction_date 
)
SELECT   d.*
,    SUM (debit_total - credit_total)
       OVER (ORDER BY transaction_date) AS balance_to_date
FROM    daily_summary d
WHERE account_number ='0Z8NQN6JZRZWFPX'
ORDER BY transaction_date;

ACCOUNT_NUMBER  TRANSACTION_DATE    CREDIT_TOTAL    DEBIT_TOTAL BALANCE_TO_DATE
0Z8NQN6JZRZWFPX 31-MAR-2023 00:00:00    0   1000    1000
0Z8NQN6JZRZWFPX 01-APR-2023 00:00:00    500 0   500
0Z8NQN6JZRZWFPX 02-APR-2023 00:00:00    0   2000    2500
0Z8NQN6JZRZWFPX 03-APR-2023 00:00:00    1000    0   1500
0Z8NQN6JZRZWFPX 04-APR-2023 00:00:00    0   3000    4500
```

Looking to pass in the account number and produce this output.

```
SELECT 
   CA.ACCOUNT_NUMBER,
   C.FIRST_NAME,
   C.LAST_NAME, 
   CA.IS_ACTIVE,
Get_Acccount_Balance('0Z8NQN6JZRZWFPX')
FROM CUSTOMER_ACCOUNTS CA
JOIN    customers  c  ON  ca.customer_id = c.customer_id


ACCOUNT_NUMBER  FIRST_NAME  LAST_NAME   IS_ACTIVE BALANCE 
0Z8NQN6JZRZWFPX Lisa    Saladino    Y  4500
```

Note:if the credit total is higher than the balance could be negative.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do not need a function (which would involve context-switching between SQL and PL/SQL and would likely be slower).

Instead, you can do it all in SQL and use a correlated sub-query:

```sql
SELECT CA.ACCOUNT_NUMBER,
       C.FIRST_NAME,
       C.LAST_NAME, 
       CA.IS_ACTIVE,
       (
         SELECT SUM(
                  CASE transaction_type WHEN 'C' THEN -1 ELSE 1 END 
                  * transaction_amount
                )
         FROM   transactions t
         WHERE  t.account_number = ca.account_number
       ) AS balance
FROM   CUSTOMER_ACCOUNTS CA
       INNER JOIN customers c
       ON ca.customer_id = c.customer_id;
```

or, from Oracle 12, a `LATERAL` join:

```sql
SELECT CA.ACCOUNT_NUMBER,
       C.FIRST_NAME,
       C.LAST_NAME, 
       CA.IS_ACTIVE,
       t.balance
FROM   CUSTOMER_ACCOUNTS CA
       INNER JOIN customers c
       ON ca.customer_id = c.customer_id
       CROSS JOIN LATERAL (
         SELECT SUM(
                  CASE t.transaction_type WHEN 'C' THEN -1 ELSE 1 END 
                  * t.transaction_amount
                ) AS balance
         FROM   transactions t
         WHERE  t.account_number = ca.account_number
       ) t;
```

Which, for your sample data, both output:

| ACCOUNT_NUMBER | FIRST_NAME | LAST_NAME | IS_ACTIVE | BALANCE |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| B17ARWYYZRCU2Q2 | John | Carucci | Y | *null* |
| 0T81Z07CS6LXQ7Z | John | Carucci | Y | *null* |
| YWYXC3Q5N9XZ7S | John | Carucci | Y | *null* |
| 612ZKAQ66VA3W3 | John | Carucci | Y | *null* |
| THVQD6M9LR7AVK | Bonnie | Winterbottom | Y | *null* |
| CFM9K06ZR98R9H2 | Lisa | Saladino | Y | *null* |
| 0Z8NQN6JZRZWFPX | Lisa | Saladino | Y | 4500 |
| BCHD9TW78W67S1D | Lisa | Saladino | Y | *null* |
| 01SUV1Y3BJTCFXY | Brian | Tessio | Y | *null* |
| TAJ3N5EB9ZX7AD | Brian | Tessio | Y | *null* |
| Y88JTBCP8SUFY8 | Brian | Tessio | Y | *null* |
| 06LP3CYJLS01F2L | Cheryl | Brasi | Y | *null* |
| TFWVBRC5QHQLC4 | Cheryl | Brasi | Y | *null* |
| 0Z76WT5NTLRZPTW | Peter | Clemenza | Y | *null* |

---

If you did want a function then you can wrap the code from the sub-query in a function (and maybe add [`SQL_MACRO(SCALAR)`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/21/lnpls/sql_macro-clause.html#GUID-292C3A17-2A4B-4EFB-AD38-68DF6380E5F7)).

```sql
CREATE FUNCTION get_account_balance(
  i_account_number IN VARCHAR2
) RETURN VARCHAR2 SQL_MACRO(SCALAR) IS
BEGIN
  RETURN q'{(
    SELECT SUM(
             CASE transaction_type WHEN 'C' THEN -1 ELSE 1 END 
             * transaction_amount
           )
    FROM   transactions
    WHERE  account_number = i_account_number -- one account
    OR     i_account_number IS NULL          -- all accounts
  )}';
END;
/
```

or:

```sql
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION get_account_balance(
  i_account_number IN TRANSACTIONS.ACCOUNT_NUMBER%TYPE
) RETURN TRANSACTIONS.TRANSACTION_AMOUNT%TYPE
IS
  v_balance TRANSACTIONS.TRANSACTION_AMOUNT%TYPE;
BEGIN
  SELECT SUM(
           CASE transaction_type WHEN 'C' THEN -1 ELSE 1 END 
           * transaction_amount
         )
  INTO   v_balance
  FROM   transactions
  WHERE  account_number = i_account_number -- one account
  OR     i_account_number IS NULL;         -- all accounts

  RETURN v_balance;
END;
/
```

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/lngoKGGJ)

Comment: MTO I'm circling around to this project again and have a follow up question if you don't mind. I want use the function solution you provided to get either 1 or all accounts (get_account_balance) is that possible with the solution you provided?

Answer (score 1):

You don't need a function for this. Build a view that does an aggregation and reuse it. You may also "push" filters into this quite simple view with [`MERGE`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/sqlrf/Comments.html#GUID-7C4C7728-B202-413B-9F91-EC1B8D63F3B0) hint for `JOIN` queries (or the database may do it automatically if complex view merging is enabled in the instance). `WHERE` filter for an account will be automatically pushed.

```
/*To demonstrate pushdown benefit*/
create index ix_trx_account
on transactions(account_number)
```

```
create view v_account_balance
  as
select
  account_number,
  sum(decode(transaction_type, 'D', 1, 'C', -1) * transaction_amount) AS balance_to_date
from transactions
group by account_number
```

With more data in the `transactions` table than it was in the question:

```
insert  into transactions(
account_number, transaction_type, transaction_amount, transaction_date)
SELECT '0Z8NQN6JZRZWFPX', 'D', 1000 * LEVEL, date '2023-03-29' + level * interval '2' day from dual
          connect by level <= 3
union all
SELECT '0Z8NQN6JZRZWFPX', 'C', 500 * LEVEL, date '2023-03-30' + level * interval '2' day from dual
          connect by level <= 2

union all
SELECT 'TFWVBRC5QHQLC4', 'D', 1100 * LEVEL, date '2023-03-29' + level * interval '2' day from dual
          connect by level <= 3
union all
SELECT 'TFWVBRC5QHQLC4', 'C', 200 * LEVEL, date '2023-03-30' + level * interval '2' day from dual
          connect by level <= 2
```

```
select /*+ gather_plan_statistics*/
  a.*
  , coalesce(bal.balance_to_date, 0) as balance_to_date
from customer_accounts a
  left join v_account_balance bal
  on a.account_number = bal.account_number
```

| ACCOUNT_NUMBER | CUSTOMER_ID | VENDOR_ID | IS_ACTIVE | BALANCE_TO_DATE |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| B17ARWYYZRCU2Q2 | D379171 | 8 | Y | 0 |
| 0T81Z07CS6LXQ7Z | D379171 | 7 | Y | 0 |
| YWYXC3Q5N9XZ7S | D379171 | 7 | Y | 0 |
| 612ZKAQ66VA3W3 | D379171 | 4 | Y | 0 |
| THVQD6M9LR7AVK | E379466 | 5 | Y | 0 |
| CFM9K06ZR98R9H2 | K380989 | 1 | Y | 0 |
| 0Z8NQN6JZRZWFPX | K380989 | 2 | Y | 4500 |
| BCHD9TW78W67S1D | K380989 | 3 | Y | 0 |
| 01SUV1Y3BJTCFXY | X098533 | 1 | Y | 0 |
| TAJ3N5EB9ZX7AD | X098533 | 2 | Y | 0 |
| Y88JTBCP8SUFY8 | X098533 | 3 | Y | 0 |
| 06LP3CYJLS01F2L | Y098273 | 7 | Y | 0 |
| TFWVBRC5QHQLC4 | Y098273 | 8 | Y | 6000 |
| 0Z76WT5NTLRZPTW | Z098555 | 10 | Y | 0 |

```
select *
from dbms_xplan.display_cursor(format => '+PREDICATE')


SQL_ID  6fqbu5hrg75mz, child number 0
-------------------------------------
select /*+ gather_plan_statistics*/   a.*   ,
coalesce(bal.balance_to_date, 0) as balance_to_date from
customer_accounts a   left join v_account_balance bal   on
a.account_number = bal.account_number
 
Plan hash value: 2666622943
 
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Id  | Operation                             | Name              | Rows  | Bytes | Cost (%CPU)| Time     |
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|   0 | SELECT STATEMENT                      |                   |       |       |     6 (100)|          |
|   1 |  HASH GROUP BY                        |                   |    22 |  1166 |     6  (17)| 00:00:01 |
|   2 |   NESTED LOOPS OUTER                  |                   |    22 |  1166 |     5   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|   3 |    TABLE ACCESS FULL                  | CUSTOMER_ACCOUNTS |    14 |   406 |     3   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|   4 |    TABLE ACCESS BY INDEX ROWID BATCHED| TRANSACTIONS      |     1 |    24 |     1   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|*  5 |     INDEX RANGE SCAN                  | IX_TRX_ACCOUNT    |     5 |       |     0   (0)|          |
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 
Predicate Information (identified by operation id):
---------------------------------------------------
 
   5 - access("A"."ACCOUNT_NUMBER"="ACCOUNT_NUMBER")
 
Note
-----
   - dynamic statistics used: dynamic sampling (level=2)
   - this is an adaptive plan
```

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/yn7PWus-)

If you also need a balance at the specific date, then `SQL_MACRO` may be a better choise to push date filter inside a query and avoid context switches.